# Why is inline-block not working in this case to center vertically?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the logo centered with `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: center` but that does not work. Would you know why and how to fix this?
Many thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/eLSbq/

```
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">Logo</div>                            
<ul class="drop_menu">
<li><a href='#'>Link 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 3</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
        </div>


.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    color: #124191;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 28px;
    height: 120px;
    display: table;
     position: fixed;
        z-index: 999999;
        opacity: 0.7;
    background: aqua;
}

.logo {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
left:0;
color: #333;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 800;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-left: 60px;
background: red;
}

 .drop_menu {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;

    right: 0;
    display: table;
    z-index: 3000;
       display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: 0;

}


.drop_menu li { display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; float: right;}

.drop_menu li a {
    padding:9px 20px;
    display:block;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;



}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#5FD367; }
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    left:0px;
    top:30px;
    background:#5FD367;
    padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:168px;
    text-indent:15px;
    background-color:#5FD367;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#005555; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LIVE DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/eLSbq/1/)**

Its working now. Take a look to my live demo

the problem is that you use at the same `display:table` and in the same class `display:table-cell`.
This is not correct.

The `display:inline-block` are correct for what you need, but i recommend you to use `float:left` instead because of the compatibility of the browser like IE 7, 8 etc..
The older browser don´t understand what `display:inline-block` mean and doesn´t apply the css properties.

i have change your css code add some `position:relative` and `top` values too..

Comment: Thanks! In your jsfiddle elements don't seem to be perfectly vertically aligned, is there a reason for that? Thanks

Comment: yes it is... because i have add a position:relative to your div and control it with the css property top... you can control it now how you want changing the top values. for example: from top:30px to top:40px.

Answer (score 1):

Greg Your layout for the Page has some serious flaws in terms of structure and css.

I suggest you to do a quality check and remove all the redundant css.

Anyways, An vertical align for an element can be done if itself is inline and parent is td as shown http://jsfiddle.net/eLSbq/6/. Display

```
display: inline
```

for logo and parent as td cell